# Body scroll Disabling after menu is shown in angular js web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am doing a web app in angular js.

I am creating a menu in it with css and js. and it is as follows.

[image]

The code for it is as follows

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="starter">
<head>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Import materialize.css-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--controllers -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/collegeCtrl.js"></script>
<!--Services -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="services/collegeService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="services/httprequestService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="constant/constant.js"></script>
<!--navbar-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar/css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar/css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar/css/component.css" />
<!-- csstransforms3d-shiv-cssclasses-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-prefixes-domprefixes-load -->
<script src="navbar/js/modernizr.custom.25376.js"></script>
<!--navbar-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="perspective" class="perspective effect-airbnb">
<div class="container indexhome">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- wrapper needed for scroll -->
    <!-- Top Navigation -->
    <div class="main clearfix">
      <p><button id="showMenu">Show Menu</button></p>
    </div>
    <!-- /main -->
    <div class="content">
      <div ui-view ng-class="transition">
        default content
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
 <!-- wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /container -->
  <nav style="background-color:transparent !important; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0), 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0), 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
 box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);  " class="outer-nav left vertical">
    <a href="#" class="icon-home">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="icon-news">News</a>
    <a href="#" class="icon-image">Images</a>
    <a href="#" class="icon-upload">Uploads</a>
    <a href="#" class="icon-star">Favorites</a>
    <a href="#" class="icon-mail">Messages</a>
    <a href="#" class="icon-lock">Security</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <!-- /perspective -->
 <script src="navbar/js/classie.js"></script>
 <script src="navbar/js/menu.js"></script>
 <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle">
   <a id="showMenu" class="btn-floating btn-large red">
     <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
   </a>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

menu.js file

```
     (function() {

        function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    // from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/989439
    function mobilecheck() {
        var check = false;
        (function(a)
    {
 if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true
})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);

    return check;
    }

    var docElem = window.document.documentElement,
        // support transitions
        support = Modernizr.csstransitions,
        // transition end event name
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' 
    ) ],
        docscroll = 0,
        // click event (if mobile use touchstart)
        clickevent = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

     function init() {
        var showMenu = document.getElementById( 'showMenu' ),
            perspectiveWrapper = document.getElementById( 'perspective' ),
            container = perspectiveWrapper.querySelector( '.container' ),
            contentWrapper = container.querySelector( '.wrapper' );

        showMenu.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            docscroll = scrollY();
            // change top of contentWrapper
            contentWrapper.style.top = docscroll * -1 + 'px';
            // mac chrome issue:
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = docscroll;
            // add modalview class
            classie.add( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
            // animate..
            setTimeout( function() { classie.add( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' 
    ); }, 25 );
        });

        container.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
            if( classie.has( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate') ) {
                var onEndTransFn = function( ev ) {
                    if( support && ( ev.target.className !== 'container' || 
     ev.propertyName.indexOf( 'transform' ) == -1 ) ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
                    classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
                    // mac chrome issue:
                    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = docscroll;
                    // change top of contentWrapper
                    contentWrapper.style.top = '0px';
                    document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
                };
                if( support ) {
                    perspectiveWrapper.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransFn );
                }
                else {
                    onEndTransFn.call();
                }
                classie.remove( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' );
            }
        });

        perspectiveWrapper.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) { return false; } );
     }

    init();

    })();
```

After opening the menu the body scroll bar is being disabled. I have been trying this from 2 days. I cant figure out what was going wrong. Please let me know where I was doing wrong.

Sorry for not formatting the code. i have tried but I am not able to format it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: TLDR; Did you try explicitly setting the overflow:auto to your body, once you close the modal/dialog.

Comment: document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll'; I have used this but it doesn't work.